# Calling function bundled by rollup.js from outside is possible?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I am using rollup.js as a bundler and I want to call one function inside the generated bundle from a piece of javascript, which is not part of the bundle.

What rollup.js does generate for me looks like this:

```
var myModule = (function () {
  'use strict';
  ...
  function myFunction(...) { ... }
  ...
}());
```

Is it somehow possible to call myFunction from outside? Or is it possible to have rollup.js generate this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you export the function, either with `export myFunction(...) {...}` or with `export { myFunction }`.

Comment: then I could import it from another script, which is also part of the bundling process. But that was not the question.

Comment: The answer was correct. Your entry module needs to export anything you want to access from outside the bundle. If `myFunction` is defined in a module *other* than your entry module, your entry module needs to re-export it.